# Which PRBS to use?

Tags: serial

How do we know which pseudo-random binary sequences (PRBS) to use for a specific use case?

**Why** is PRBS31 used to test 10G serial transceiver?

Does a list of PRBS with characteristics exist?

Edit: The link a commenter sent thinking it answers my questions, doesn't say why.

[image]

Why not PRB30? 29? 28? 27? or even 32?

Comment: Did you do your home work and search the web, including to read findings? A second's try revealed [for example this document](https://www.theiabm.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Stress-Whitepaper_January-2019.pdf). If you did, please [edit] your question and tell us why it does not help you.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Did you read the linked paper? _You_ can use any width you see fit, so what are _your_ requirements for testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ITU-T Recommendations O.151 to O.153 show the use cases in telecoms.

PRBS31 bit stream is 2 gigabits long (2^31 minus 1 to be exact) so it repeats about 4.6 times per second or every 215 milliseconds at 10 Gbps.

Shorter bitstreams would repeat more often and do not have such low frequencies. So the standard defines PRBS31 should be used for testing 10GBps Ethernet because it is a good enough test signal and it does not need to be longer.

Yes lists of PRBS signals exist, their characteritics depend on just their length which defines their repeat rate also defines how many zero or one bits you can get in a row which defines their lowest frequency content.

Due to their characteristics, usually the used bits is prime to avoid problems with pseudorandom scramblers, so PRBS31 is prime and thus both better and longer that PRBS30. PRBS32 is longer but not a prime, 28 and 27 also not primes. And PRBS29 is just shorter and not much simpler than PRBS31. They just not are often used if PRBS31 is anyway implementable, standardized, and rigorously trued and tried solution used by many others, so it is not worth it to try using a custom PRBS nobody else uses and the characterisrics are less known.

colintd brings up an excellent point; if a device like 10Gbps Ethernet IC is set to test mode to transmit out a PRBS stream to some test equipment, basically for jitter and eye diagram tests any PRBS stream might do as long as it has low enough frequencies and long enough period, but the test equipment receiving and analyzing any errors in the data must use the exact same PRBS for comparing what it should be.

Comment: Whilst loopback is typical with PRBS, in some cases one end sends, and the other decodes, so they need to use the same standards based implementation.

Comment: Thanks Justme ! Perfect, it's exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: @colintd and are also often defined in the specs/protocol.